# Explanation on "Integer.Max_Value" and Integer.Min_Value

Tags: java, oop

I am going to write a program that takes in five integer values as the test grades for some class.Then I will determine what the minimum grade is and what the maximum grade will be. Following that I am going to calculate the average. My professor specified that she wants the minimum grade stored in `Integer.Max_Value` and the maximum grade in `Integer.Min_Value`. I'm having a rough time comprehending this. Can someone please explain to me what the meaning of those statements are?

Comment: Um, "MAX_VALUE" and "MIN_VALUE" should be in all caps.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Your professor (most likely) wanted you to take these values as **initial** values for your variables.

Comment: You're not storing your variables _in_ `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `MIN_VALUE`, you're storing `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` in your variables.

Comment: Okay. But what I'm still trying to understand is why the "minimum grade" should store "Integer.MAX_VALUE" and why "maximum grade" should store "Integer.MIN_VALUE"? I would have assumed it should have bee the other way around, max with max and min with min.

Comment: The point of storing `max = Integer.MIN_VALUE` is so that `max = Math.max(max, anything)` is `anything`.

Comment: Anyway, you can create a new class called Integer which contains two fields, Min_Value and Max_Value, and assign the lowest in Min_Value and the highest in Max_Value ;)

Answer (score 3):

You must have misunderstood something. She probably wants you to have one variable that contains the highest grade (let's call it `highest`) and initialize that to Integer.MIN_VALUE and another one that contains the lowest grade (let's call it `lowest`), which is initialized to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Then you loop over all grades and if you find one that is higher than `highest`, you update `highest` to that grade and if you find one that is lower than `lowest`, you update `lowest` to that grade.

The reason for using Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE is so that you find at least one grade that is your highest (all integers are bigger or equal than MIN_VALUE) and one that is your lowest (all integers are smaller or equal than MAX_VALUE).

Comment: ohh, ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.